# Selection changed event raised when I click outside the listboxitem 

Tags: wpf, listbox, wpf-controls, listboxitem, listbox-control

I have Listbox and some listboxitems. After selecting few items, if I click empty space between the listboxitems, selection changed event raised and previous selection gone.

How to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: How can empty space comes between listboxitems

Comment: @KishoreJangid I am using DataTemplate for the ListBoxItems, which having some spaces between two ListBoxItems